# copying/moving document in alfresco by changing its type

Tags: ftp, alfresco, cmis, alfresco-share

I am trying to upload a big file in alfresco, since this cause a problem with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I decide to use ftp to upload the document in alfresco. Another problem is introduced with that; I can't create a document with the type I want.

So I am thinking, after I upload the document in alfresco, and then to copy/move the document to another folder (again in alfresco) by changing its type. I am not sure if this is possible. I try to look around no good clue about it.

can some one please tell me if it is possible? if so how ?

thanks,

Comment: Why not upload it with CMIS? With CMIS you can control the type...

Comment: it is because of the big file size I am getting: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error. so, CMIS is not convenient way.

Comment: Could you perhaps be using the old CMIS endpoint, not the new one? The old ones were largely JS based, the new OpenCMIS powered ones ought to be fine with large files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an incoming rule on the folder which specializes the type.

If you use Share, add the content type in your `share-config-custom.xml`
 condition DocumentLibrary. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792131/alfresco-share-not-showing-subtype-or-custom-type) you can find how to specify it.