# How to suppress multiple email notification from javascript

Tags: javascript, email, alfresco, alfresco-share

Here is my java script

```
var siteGroup = "GROUP_EMAIL_CONTRIBUTORS";
var mail = actions.create("mail");
mail.parameters.to_many = siteGroup;
var url = "Click http://pc1:8080/share/page/site/" + document.properties.name + "/dashboard" + "   to join the site";
mail.parameters.subject="New Site Created in Community";
mail.parameters.text=url;
//execute action against a document
mail.execute(document);
```

The `siteGroup` has three members with three different email address. The problem is this java script is sending three email notification to all the three users. If I add one more member then each will get four email. How to suppress this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need create a subtype of st:site to make sure it only triggers on the site.

There are 2 options:

1. Change your email.js so it checks if the document type is **st:site**
2. A better way is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792131/alfresco-share-not-showing-subtype-or-custom-type), were you can add the st:site as a sub-type in the share-config-custom.xml so it's selectable in the drop-down next to the default Folder & Content types

Example, this snippet needs to be between de alfresco-config tags:

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">
        <types>
             <type name="cm:folder">
                <subtype name="st:site" />
            </type> 
        </types>
    </config>
```

Comment: Is this correct??
`<types>
     <type name="cm:content">
            <subtype name="st:site" />
     </type>

     <type name="cm:folder">
<subtype name="st:site" />
     </type>
  </types>`

Comment: No, st:site is a subtype of cm:folder and not of cm:content ;)

Comment: Now..`<types>
     <type name="cm:folder">
            <subtype name="st:site" />
     </type>
  </types>`

Comment: I added the above code in share-cofig-custom.xml but I didnt get drop-down next to the default Folder & Content types

Comment: Alternatively can I use this 
`var doc = search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/eafb46a7-a139-42e1-b297-71402d279b68");
mail.execute(doc);` in my java script??

Comment: It should work, have you checkt the example i've provided. Otherwise you could copy the entire DocumentLibrary and add the subtype in it. If that doesn't work you could add replace=true to it

Comment: no you could just leave your rule as it is. And change your script with if (document.typeShort == "st:site") and then send the mail

Comment: No it is not working still it is sending duplicate mails

Comment: It is a registered bug in alfresco. 
https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-10945